# HttpWebRequest keep alive - how is the connection reused by .net?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, http-headers

Hy,
I am using HttpWebRequest in 10 concurent threads to download a list of images. I sorted the images after the hostName so each of this threads are getting an image from the same Hostname.

```
HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
myReq.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 10;
myReq.Timeout = 2000;
myReq.KeepAlive = true;

HttpWebResponse myResp = (HttpWebResponse )myReq.GetResponse();
```

After the program is running for a while I keep getting timeout exception. 
My thoughts are that I get exception because maybe the Host server has some limitation regarding the concurent connections from the same user.

So how is a connection reused in .net ?
In my program each thread is creating a new connection to a hostname, or is reusing the existing one because of the KeepAlive property ??

Comment: What was the result of "In my program each thread is creating a new connection to a hostname, or is reusing the existing one because of the KeepAlive property ??"

Comment: For the servers that supported http 1.1 protocol, it was reusing the connection. It was also important to request images from the same domain in the same time, so that I don't open more then 10 connections too often. .Net has a way of doing that automatically even if you are finishing one request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the problem was some servers that were using http/1.0. 
HttpWebRequest  is [using 100](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.3) Continue behaviour but the server doesn't support it.

So i changed the property `System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue` to `false` and then everything worked fine.